# Phalcon won't load when php run from command line

Tags: php, cron, freebsd, phalcon

I hove some CRON jobs that run on my server (FreeBSD 9.2).  When they try to run, they fail because "phalcon.so can't load because symbol ps_globals is undefined." (I don't have the exact error in front of me.)  I have seen this ps_globals business before, and it had to do with sessions.

Has anyone else seen this error or have any idea how to fix it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the `session.so` extension *before* loading `phalcon.so`.